# Accessing enviroment variable in testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, environment-variables, testcafe

I am having trouble accessing environment variable that I have set permanently in windows using setx. I have set a path to the download folder that I would access in my test code.

```
C:\Users\XXXX>echo %DOWNLOADS%
    C:/Users/XXXX/Downloads/
```

In my test code -

```
import { Selector, fixture } from 'testcafe';
fixture`Auto Test`
  .page`http://XXXXXX/index.html`.beforeEach(async (browser) => {
  let directory;
  if (browser.browser.os.name === 'Windows') {
        directory = env.DOWNLOADS;
```

I see following error -
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can acess the environment variable like

```
process.env.DEV_MODE
```

DEV_MODE is my environment variable

sample code

```
  if (process.env.DEV_MODE) {
    baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';
  } else {
    baseUrl = config.API.BaseUrl;
  }
```

Comment: Cant I use a variable set by me which in this case is %DOWNLOADS% by using process.env.DOWNLOADS??

Comment: yes, set an environment variable in windows or Linux and you can use process.env to access it. https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs

Comment: Thanks It worked. I had restarted windows to for env variable to take effect and it is working